# Adding css transitions to a growing list of items

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a component that starts out with an empty list of items / boxes and as the list grows, the previous items are pushed down in the que. You can see the below snippet for an example. How do I add css transitions such that you can visually see the items move from their previous position to the next position down? Thanks!

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      count: 0
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.getItems = this.getItems.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({
      count: this.state.count + 1,
    });
  }
  
  getItems() {
    let items = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < this.state.count; j++) {
      items.push(<div className="item">This is a box {j}</div>)
    }
    return items.reverse();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Add box</button>
        {this.getItems()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}



ReactDOM.render(<App />, app);
```

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid green !important;
}


.item {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use animation on max-height; 
But you have to know the size of your .item, max-height:100% isn't working on animation.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      count: 0
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.getItems = this.getItems.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({
      count: this.state.count + 1,
    });
  }
  
  getItems() {
    let items = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < this.state.count; j++) {
      items.push(<div className="item">This is a box {j}</div>)
    }
    return items.reverse();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Add box</button>
        {this.getItems()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}



ReactDOM.render(<App />, app);
```

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid green !important;
}


.item {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 20px;

  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}
@keyframes example {
  from { max-height: 0px;}
  to { max-height: 40px;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify. Let's say I have boxes 2, 1, and 0 and am about to add box 3. I want to have a transition such that we can watch box 2 move from it's current position to the position of box 1, so on and so forth.

Comment: @Arthur created a correct solution, but due to the fact that the inserted boxes are not keyed correctly, react recreates the whole list of divs, during reconciliation phase merges the existing divs just replacing their content and adds a new div at the end. If you modify your code to `items.push(<div className="item" key={j}>This is a box {j}</div>)` it will work - react will know that the div with highest number is the new one.